# Iterate Over JavaScript Object, Compare Values and Return Key

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, time

I have an object `idTime` which has key value pairs of ids and the time an action was taken.
I'm having trouble iterating over it in JavaScript by value, and then retrieving the key from it. Here's the exact object:

```
const idTime = {
  "3b2f93b8-72a7-4d85-a366-bb17f830b43c": "2021-07-29 08:51:31+00:00",
  "533e9079-7dd2-4719-b502-69a4ca4b60e6": "2021-06-30 22:14:42+00:00",
  "5df5ba4b-2e87-4bdd-a14e-49db6bb11770": "2021-07-29 16:46:38+00:00",
  "e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455": "2021-07-29 16:51:05+00:00",
};
```

I know how to print them out:

```
  const printIds = () => {
    for (var key in idTime ) {
      if (idMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + idTime [key]);
      }
    }
  };
```

I need to retrieve the latest `id`, which in this case is `e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455`, so I'll need to compare the times in this exact form. I've read abit about the JavaScript reducer but I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: `Object.keys(idTime)` returns list of keys and `Object.values(idTime` returns list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the item or ID which is the latest. For that, you can sort the `idTime` object in descending order then take the first item like the latest one.

For performing sorting you have to convert the object into an array. For that, you can use `Object.entries()` so that we can preserve both `key` and `value`.

```js
const idTime = {
  "3b2f93b8-72a7-4d85-a366-bb17f830b43c": "2021-07-29 08:51:31+00:00",
  "533e9079-7dd2-4719-b502-69a4ca4b60e6": "2021-06-30 22:14:42+00:00",
  "5df5ba4b-2e87-4bdd-a14e-49db6bb11770": "2021-07-29 16:46:38+00:00",
  "e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455": "2021-07-29 16:51:05+00:00",
};

// This makes an array of array with [key, value] pair
const entries = Object.entries(idTime);

// Sort the entries array desc order
entries.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b[1]).getTime() - new Date(a[1]).getTime();
});

// The first entry is the latest item after sorting
console.log('latest id: ', entries[0][0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: @clattenburgcake consider the sort complexity if data is large since it can be done in O(n) without sort, though not a problem for given input.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const idTime = {
  "3b2f93b8-72a7-4d85-a366-bb17f830b43c": "2021-07-29 08:51:31+00:00",
  "533e9079-7dd2-4719-b502-69a4ca4b60e6": "2021-06-30 22:14:42+00:00",
  "5df5ba4b-2e87-4bdd-a14e-49db6bb11770": "2021-07-29 16:46:38+00:00",
  "e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455": "2021-07-29 16:51:05+00:00",
};

const maxDate = new Date(Math.max(...Object.values(idTime).map(x => Date.parse(x))));    
console.log({maxDate});

const maxDateId = Object.keys(idTime).filter(id=>Date.parse(idTime[id])==Date.parse(maxDate))[0];
console.log({maxDateId});
```

Comment: It's even easier to do with one single iteration by only keeping track of the max date and ID values.

Comment: @VLAZ yes i know for example we can replace whole thing with good old for loop and all but it's just that i am more of a streams, map and filter guy.

Comment: You can do a `.reduce()`, too.

Comment: Yes definately, that would basically reduce directly to the required object.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort the object's entries on the basis of time in descending order and get the id of the latest date.

```js
const idTime = {
  "3b2f93b8-72a7-4d85-a366-bb17f830b43c": "2021-07-29 08:51:31+00:00",
  "533e9079-7dd2-4719-b502-69a4ca4b60e6": "2021-06-30 22:14:42+00:00",
  "5df5ba4b-2e87-4bdd-a14e-49db6bb11770": "2021-07-29 16:46:38+00:00",
  "e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455": "2021-07-29 16:51:05+00:00",
};
let sortedIdTime = Object.entries(idTime).sort((curr,nxt)=>new Date(nxt[1]) - new Date(curr[1]));

let firstEntry = sortedIdTime[0];
let resultantId = firstEntry[0];

console.log(resultantId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ***array sort method*** and ***array destructure***;

```js
const idTime = {
  "3b2f93b8-72a7-4d85-a366-bb17f830b43c": "2021-07-29 08:51:31+00:00",
  "533e9079-7dd2-4719-b502-69a4ca4b60e6": "2021-06-30 22:14:42+00:00",
  "5df5ba4b-2e87-4bdd-a14e-49db6bb11770": "2021-07-29 16:46:38+00:00",
  "e0adeb25-9870-4185-a947-ae6f4aae2455": "2021-07-29 16:51:05+00:00",
};

const sortedTime = Object
  .entries(idTime)
  .sort(([key, value] )=> new Date(value[1]) - new Date(value[0]))[0][0]
  

console.log(sortedTime);
```

Comment: Your sorting comparator does nothing useful. It needs to take *two* parameters. Instead, you only take one then convert the second and first character of the value of the first parameter into dates. That would be `new Date("0")` and `new Date("1")` for all of these.